# Hi I am getting a NoSuchMethodError everytime I run the program in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the error I get in my terminal:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building SearchScreen(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<AppData>], state: _SearchScreenState#10790):
The getter 'placeName' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: placeName
```

And this is the Searchscreen code:

```
class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchScreenState createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen>
{
  TextEditingController pickUpTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController dropOffTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  List<PlacePredictions> placePredictionList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    String placeAddress = Provider.of<AppData>(context).pickUpLocation.placeName ?? "";
    pickUpTextEditingController.text = placeAddress;
```

It mainly happens when I click a widget in the app and the screen just goes red with this error.

Comment: This is a null-safety issue, looks like pickUpLocation is null? Try putting `pickUpLocation?.placeName ?? "";` instead of `pickUpLocation.placeName ?? "";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that your provider provides `null` value for `pickUpLocation`. so first check your provider to solve this problem. Although it is better to handle this problem in the provider, you can use this code for null safety:

```
String placeAddress = Provider.of<AppData>(context).pickUpLocation?.placeName ?? "";
```

Comment: Thank you so much Hasan! this worked for me, you saved me so much of time,

Comment: @kishor420 happy to help. I would be grateful if you set my answer as an acceptable answer. see this link: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers